# SML Iteration vs Recursion

Tags: recursion, iteration, sml

I have a simple and possibly ignorant question. I am working on an assignment for a programming languages course, at this point we are working in SML. Can anyone tell me how to best step through a list? We have a question that asks us to count the number of negative numbers in a given list. Is it best to do this with recursion or iteration and is there documentation for SML which would help me while learning the language?

Comment: Since you're taking a course in programming languages, your teacher should be able to provide you with a suitable list of learning materials. (Although it's a bit odd that your teacher hasn't said "you want to use recursion", and that iteration has even been mentioned in the context of SML.)

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone tell me how to best step through a list?

By pattern matching on the list's structure: Either the list is empty, and there is no more stepping through, or the list has at least one more element, in which case we do something with that element and step through the rest of the list.

```
fun sum [] = 0
  | sum (x::xs) = x + sum xs
```

> count the number of negative numbers in a given list

Show an attempt of this so that you can be provided with feedback.

> Is it best to do this with recursion or iteration

Recursion.

> is there documentation for SML which would help me while learning the language?

Your course should provide or recommend textbooks.

The shortest intro I know is [Learn X in Y minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/standard-ml/) where X = Standard ML.